# How to install system images offline in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I am using android Studio in Iran and Google restricted its services in my country. I used a proxy software to download SDK and install android Studio components online and after that I tried the same thing for installing AVD but the download always fails even when I use proxies.

My main question is how can I manually download and install system images for AVD on my system ? I have download System Image for the Android API Level 21 or Android L (Lollipop) but it does not show up in the AVD list, I changed the folder name in the directory "Sdk\system-images" to "android-21" but still no result when I try to create an AVD.

Please firstly show me a way to get system images manually and secondly tell me If I am using the right name for my API Level 21 system image folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using Google AVD: it's heavy and slow... Try to use GeanyMotion it's faster to run, completely free of charge

https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/